# .Net core 3.0 API doesn't bind properties with hyphen

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, .net-core

**Reviewed the question as it was not received well the last time. Hope I have provided all the required information below.**

I have a basic API controller and my Json object doesn't seem to bind to the model properly. The root object binds but the property with hyphen in its name doesn't bind. Unfortunately, I cannot drop the hyphen in the property name.

How do I get the property to bind correctly?

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestCoreAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        // POST: api/Test
        [HttpPost]
        public string Post([FromBody] TestPayload testPayload)
        {
            if (testPayload == null)
            {
                return "Test payload is empty";
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(testPayload.TestProperty))
            {
                return "Test property is empty";
            }

            return "Valid input - " + testPayload.TestProperty;
        }
    }

    [JsonObject("test-payload")]
    public class TestPayload
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "test-property")]
        public string TestProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the call I'm making to the API

```
POST /api/test HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json

{"test-property":"some string value"}
```

Comment: The usual reason for this is that the JSON does not match the model. Without also seeing your model, it's impossible to say for sure if this is your issue.

Comment: Before someone asks here is the model definition too `[JsonObject("test-payload")]
 public class TestPayload
 {
  [JsonProperty("test-string")]
  public string TestString { get; set; }
 }`

Comment: And there you go, your model doesn't match.

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Your root object, has a property `"test-payload"`, which is a subobject. That subobject has a property `"test-string"`, which is a `string` property. You need to represent both objects here, not just the nested one.

Comment: JSON is really simple to represent in C#. Anytime you see `{ }` you have an object (represent with `class` in C#), anytime you see `[ ]` you have an array (represent with  `List<T>` or `T[]`, etc. in C#), and everything else is a simple property like `string` or `int`. If you're not sure, Visual Studio has `Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes`.

Comment: What should my model look like for this payload to be deserialized? `{"test-payload":{"test-string":"test string data"}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207444/discussion-between-display-name-and-john).

Comment: What version of.net core do you use? And can you show ConfigureServices part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you adding `AddNewtonsoftJson()` to your services in `Startup.ConfigureServices` ?  If not, the new `System.Text.Json` is being used, not Newtonsoft.  I think you'll need to do `AddNewtonSoftJson()` as i'm fairly sure `System.Text.Json` doesn't support 'kebab case' bindings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support

Comment: For newtonsoft, you need services`.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson()` whereas the new framework Json does't require the mvc, it can just `AddControllers()`

Answer (score 5):

Net Core 3.1 does bind hyphens. Either way, the two options are `Newtonsoft.Json` or new-in-core-3 `System.Text.Json`, and they use slightly different `Attribute` names:

```
public class PostModel
{
    //This one if you are using Newtonsoft.Json
    //The Nuget dependency is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "kebab-case-json-field")]

    //This one of you are using the new System.Text.Json.Serialization
    [JsonPropertyName("kebab-case-json-field")]

    public string kebabCaseProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Meanwhile, in your `Startup.cs`, to use Newtonsoft, you need `AddMvc()`, whereas for new System.Text.Json, you don't. These both worked for me:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //if using NewtonSoft
    services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    //if using System.Text.Json.
    //This is the code that core 3 `dotnet new webapi` generates
    services.AddControllers();
}
```