# asp.net core 3 webapi : Route or Bind parameters (query or posted) with hyphens in their name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I hoped that an Action signature like

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post(string thirdPartySpecifiedParameter)
```

would automagically bind a hyphenated query parameter

```
controller?third-party-specified-parameter=value
```

or a JSON posted value

```
{ "third-party-specified-parameter":"value" }
```

and assign it to `thirdPartySpecifiedParameter` but it doesn't. The *routing* docs deal with the example of mapping hyphens in Urls paths, but not with *binding* parameter & field names which are invalid for C#.

What's the simplest way to bind the incoming hyphenated name to the matching C# parameter?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556605/5233410

Comment: Most likely you are using the new default `System.Text.Json` which can't handle that just yet

Comment: This is just with the `dotnet new webapi` template on aspnetcore 3.1.3, the template is uptodate and the only code I've added is the one method described here.

Comment: nb I've editted the Q as I realised that I'm really asking about *binding* not routing

Comment: Nkosi, yes I see your point -- for json posting that's the issue. Feel free to write an answer, otherwise I'll write one to cover both my use cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the problem is about Binding not Routing, and the simplest available solution is using a `BindingAttribute` provide by .Net. The limitation -- not a new one -- is that you need a different BindingAttribute for Query parameters vs Json Body vs Form post.

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post(
    [FromBody]PostModel model,
    [FromQuery(Name="kebab-case-query-param")]string kebabCaseQueryParam)
```

The `[FromQuery(Name="...")]` deals with query string parameters

For Json posts, you must use the `[FromBody]` attribute in the method signature, *and* define a model, *and* put an `Attribute` on the property to bind. `Newtonsoft.Json` or new-in-core-3 `System.Text.Json` use slightly different `Attribute` names:

```
public class PostModel
{
    //This one if you are using Newtonsoft.Json
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "kebab-case-json-field")]

    //This one of you are using the new System.Text.Json.Serialization
    [JsonPropertyName("kebab-case-json-field")]

    public string kebabCaseProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Back in your `Startup.cs`, to use Newtonsoft, you also need `AddMvc()`, whereas for new `System.Text.Json`, you don't. Something like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //if using NewtonSoft
        services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    
        //if using System.Text.Json
        //dotnet new webapi for netcore3 generates this code:
        services.AddControllers();
        
    }
```

To use Newtonsoft Json this way under NetCore3, you depend on nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`