# Bind request containing Header property with Hyphens to .Net Core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, post, asp.net-core-webapi

Referencing [.Net core 3.0 API doesn't bind properties with hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60123613/net-core-3-0-api-doesnt-bind-properties-with-hyphen), I tried the code in .NET Core 3.1 to accept a hyphenated property name (test-property) from the header and translate it to my class's internal name (testProperty). I'm using System.Text.Json. Here's my code:

```
    [HttpPut]
    public string Put([FromHeader]PostModel header)
    {
        return header.testProperty;
    }
    public class PostModel
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("test-property")]
        [FromHeader]
        [Required] 
        public string testProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

When I call the API with the property test-property in the header, it returns the validation error "The testProperty field is required." When I change the header to pass in testproperty instead of test-property, the API runs fine and returns the always-interesting string "Hello world". I feel like I'm missing something obvious but cannot for the life of me figure out what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JsonPropertyName` specifies the property name that is present in the JSON when serializing and deserializing. If you send data from body with json, it works well. What you did is from header, you need change like below:

```
public class PostModel
{
    [JsonPropertyName("test-property")]
    [FromHeader(Name = "test-property")]
    [Required]
    public string testProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks like the JsonPropertyName annotation is not required, just the FromHeader annotation.